# Function for computing percentage of how similar an array of text strings are to each other in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-comparison

Lets say I have the following array of strings, `var = array_of_strings["abc","abcd"]`

My goal is to run a function and have this return *roughly* **75%** (**0.75**).  Implying that the results are *roughly* 75% in common.  Roughly being defined as within a certain error range, let us say 5% or some settable number.

I'm currently using the the Levenshtein algorithm to compute differences in the strings, however, this is extremely slow and taxing on the CPU in my situation as **the strings I'm using are *thousands* and *thousands* of lines long**.

Levenshtein gives me what the differences are; and while useful in certain situations, my particular use case is simply looking to see what percentage the strings are roughly different from each other and not what each difference actually is necessarily.

The current levenshtein algorithm I'm using is below (which I borrowed from another answer here on stackoverflow).  It will return how many differences it found which I can then use to calculate a percentage difference, but it's very slow! Sometimes taking a couple of seconds to run and freezes up the computer as well.

```
async function levenshtein(s, t) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("levenshtein active");
        if (s === t) {
            return 0;
        }
        var n = s.length, m = t.length;
        if (n === 0 || m === 0) {
            return n + m;
        }
        var x = 0, y, a, b, c, d, g, h, k;
        var p = new Array(n);
        for (y = 0; y < n;) {
            p[y] = ++y;
        }

        for (; (x + 3) < m; x += 4) {
            var e1 = t.charCodeAt(x);
            var e2 = t.charCodeAt(x + 1);
            var e3 = t.charCodeAt(x + 2);
            var e4 = t.charCodeAt(x + 3);
            c = x;
            b = x + 1;
            d = x + 2;
            g = x + 3;
            h = x + 4;
            for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
                k = s.charCodeAt(y);
                a = p[y];
                if (a < c || b < c) {
                    c = (a > b ? b + 1 : a + 1);
                }
                else {
                    if (e1 !== k) {
                        c++;
                    }
                }

                if (c < b || d < b) {
                    b = (c > d ? d + 1 : c + 1);
                }
                else {
                    if (e2 !== k) {
                        b++;
                    }
                }

                if (b < d || g < d) {
                    d = (b > g ? g + 1 : b + 1);
                }
                else {
                    if (e3 !== k) {
                        d++;
                    }
                }

                if (d < g || h < g) {
                    g = (d > h ? h + 1 : d + 1);
                }
                else {
                    if (e4 !== k) {
                        g++;
                    }
                }
                p[y] = h = g;
                g = d;
                d = b;
                b = c;
                c = a;
            }
        }

        for (; x < m;) {
            var e = t.charCodeAt(x);
            c = x;
            d = ++x;
            for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
                a = p[y];
                if (a < c || d < c) {
                    d = (a > d ? d + 1 : a + 1);
                }
                else {
                    if (e !== s.charCodeAt(y)) {
                        d = c + 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        d = c;
                    }
                }
                p[y] = d;
                c = a;
            }
            h = d;
        }

        resolve(h);
    })
}
```

My question is, is there a way to **calculate the difference faster** when large string sets are used? In my case accuracy is not too important just as long as a rough difference is known of a certain percentage.

For example, if a research paper was published and I have the original paper and the students paper I want to know if ***roughly 10%*** of the students paper is plagiarized.

Maybe if I cut a random parts out of the strings this can help to save on time but this feels very dirty/inefficient.

Comment: One thing you could do if you have many string sets that you run is to parallelize the workload, look up JS Workers on goolge. Another thing that could potentially make this much faster is to rewrite this to a fast compiled language, JavaScript is very slow compared to compiled languages.

Comment: I've a feeling that code could be optimized,  all those `charCodeAt` are going to be really inefficient, you can convert the string to an array first..  It probably should be done this way anyway, as it will make it unicode compatible.  Also the freezes can be stopped by using webworkers, this looks like a great example to use them..

Comment: Also -> `return new Promise(`  is totally pointless, there is no async code here.

Comment: Actually forget the `charCodeAt` speed, it's actually doing a UTF-16 indexing, and since strings are stored as UTF-16, it's pretty fast.  But still, converting to Array helps with unicode issues..

Comment: @keith
 Unfortunately I'm stuck using javascript, my particular code was async because I didn't want it to lock up the system while it was running, that is why it returns a promise.  I'm using await in another routine which calls this.